# Error using ee.Filter.maxDifference in GEE Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm trying to perform a linear interpolation to fill gaps in Sentinel-2 time series. At some point I need to create a filter using `ee.Filter.maxDifference` as explained [here](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/end-to-end-gee.html#temporal-interpolation):

```
var days = 45;
var millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)

var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: millis,
  leftField: 'system:time_start',
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
})
```

This works correctly in the code editor but when I translate it to Python:

```
days = 45
millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
    difference: millis,
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
})
```

I obtain the following error: **NameError: name 'difference' is not defined**

It also does not work using a Python dictionary with a string keyword:

```
days = 45
millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
    'difference': millis,
    'leftField': 'system:time_start',
    'rightField': 'system:time_start'
})
```

I obtain the following error: **EEException: Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): {'difference': <ee.ee_number.Number object at 0x0000022C4309F040>, 'leftField': 'system:time_start', 'rightField': 'system:time_start'}**

What am I missing?

Comment: The dictionary keywords must be defined as strings, example: `'difference': millis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for `ee.Filter.maxDifference` to be able to recognize the arguments provided in the dictionary keywords it is necessary to pass the dictionary as a `**kwargs` variable using `**` operator. I think this solved the problem.

The code would look like this:

```
millis = ee.Number(days).multiply(1000*60*60*24)
maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference(**{
    'difference': millis,
    'leftField': 'system:time_start',
    'rightField': 'system:time_start'
})
```

Info about this in the GEE [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/python_install).